# What happens when the Mac OS menu bar fills up with too many icons?

Tags: macos, mac, menu-bar

When the Mac OS menu bar fills up with too many icons on the upper right side, and begins to encroach on the space of the menu text, will the OS begin to make the menu bar taller and wrap the icons?  Or will the icons simply overflow / overlay the menu text?

This question assumes that Bartender is not installed.

Answer (score 4):

You can test it by changing your display resolution ;)

[low resolution -> overlay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlE4W.png)

[image]

[normal resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jca39.png)

[image]

Comment: Wow, so Mac OS seems to just randomly hide text menu items? - That's wild!

Comment: @sean2078 No, it's the other way around. mac OS hides menu bar icons to display all text menu items.

Comment: I see - I was thrown by the above screenshots thinking the menus were of the same app, but they're not ( Mail vs. Finder ) .. Still is the hiding of menu bar icons random and if some are hidden how are they accessed?